# Extend Sitecore Expiration License

Tags: license

I want to know if there is a way to extend `Sitecore license module` to include a validation on a custom license.

I know there is a way to extend it in content editor by adding processor in `getContentEditorWarnings` pipeline, but is there a way to extend it in the published site in CD as well?